# С++ Зависимость классов друг от друга

Tags: c++, классы, include, зависимости, циклические-зависимости

Я еще только изучаю С++ и решил сделать свой проект графического интерфейса с нуля (с использованием SDL2) и пока делал классы столкнулся с проблемой:
в общем виде , класс А использует метод класса В, при этом класс В использует методы класса А.

Вопрос, а как делать так, чтобы оно скомпилировалось? Как обойти эту проблему? Forward def помогает только в случае указателей, а у меня именно вызов функций.
P.S. надеюсь не ошибся с оформлением поста

ButtonClasses.h:

```
    #ifndef BUTTONCLASSES_H
#define BUTTONCLASSES_H

#include <SDL.h>
//#include "viewPort.h"
//#include "menu.h"

struct menuMachine;
struct viewPort;
struct menu;



menu* currentmenu;

struct B_WARP : public button
{
menu* nextM=nullptr;
menuMachine* myMenuMachine;

void activate() override;
void draw(SDL_Renderer*) override;
void target(SDL_Renderer*) override;
~B_WARP();


};

   

struct B_HSCROLLER : public button
{
    int leftbound, rightbound;

    SDL_Rect background;
    SDL_Color backcolor;

    SDL_Rect arrowL, arrowR;
    SDL_Color arrowcolor[2];

    void activate() override;
    void draw(SDL_Renderer*) override;
    void target(SDL_Renderer*) override;
};





#endif // BUTTONCLASSES_H
```

ButtonClasses.cpp:

```
    #include "buttonClasses.h"
#include "buttonFlist.h"  



extern SDL_Point mouse, mouseL;
extern int dx, dy;
  

void B_WARP::activate()
{
    if(nextM!=nullptr)
    {
//    menuMachine* cmenu=(menuMachine*)object;
    currentmenu=nextM;
    }
}

void B_WARP::draw(SDL_Renderer* nren)
{
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColorExt(nren,currst);
    SDL_RenderDrawRect(nren,&butt);
}

void B_WARP::target(SDL_Renderer* nren)
    {
        SDL_Color tempSt=currst;
        tempSt.a=200;
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColorExt(nren,tempSt);
        SDL_RenderDrawRect(nren,&butt);
    }

 B_WARP:: ~B_WARP()
{
    if(nextM!=nullptr)
        delete [] nextM;
}    


void B_HSCROLLER::activate()
    {
        int i;
    //check speed!!
    //да да, return гораздо удлобнее,чем флаговая переменная и куча проверок

         if(SDL_PointInRect(&mouse,&arrowL))
         {
             butt.x-=2;
             if(butt.x<leftbound)
                butt.x+=2;
             return;
         }

         if(SDL_PointInRect(&mouse,&arrowR))
         {
             butt.x+=2;
             if((butt.x+butt.w)>rightbound)
                butt.x-=2;
             return;
         }

        butt.x+=dx;
        if((butt.x<leftbound)||(butt.x+butt.w)>rightbound)
        butt.x-=dx;
        else
        {
            for(i=0;i<vp->buttamount;i++)
            {
                vp->pads[i].butt.x=dx*(vp->hscrollspeed);
            }
        }
    }

void B_HSCROLLER::draw(SDL_Renderer* nren)
        {
            SDL_SetRenderDrawColorExt(nren,backcolor);
            SDL_RenderDrawRect(nren,&background);
            SDL_SetRenderDrawColorExt(nren,currst);
            SDL_RenderDrawRect(nren,&butt);
            SDL_SetRenderDrawColorExt(nren,arrowcolor[0]);
            SDL_RenderDrawRect(nren,&arrowL);
            SDL_SetRenderDrawColorExt(nren,arrowcolor[1]);
            SDL_RenderDrawRect(nren,&arrowR);
        }

void B_HSCROLLER::target(SDL_Renderer* nren)
    {
        SDL_Color tempSt;

        if(SDL_PointInRect(&mouse,&butt))
        {
            tempSt=currst;
            tempSt.a=200;
            SDL_SetRenderDrawColorExt(nren,tempSt);
            SDL_RenderDrawRect(nren,&butt);
        }


        if(SDL_PointInRect(&mouse,&arrowL))
        {
            tempSt=arrowcolor[0];
            tempSt.a=200;
            SDL_SetRenderDrawColorExt(nren,tempSt);
            SDL_RenderDrawRect(nren,&arrowL);
        }


        if(SDL_PointInRect(&mouse,&arrowR))
        {
            tempSt=arrowcolor[1];
            tempSt.a=200;
            SDL_SetRenderDrawColorExt(nren,tempSt);
            SDL_RenderDrawRect(nren,&arrowR);
        }

    }


void B_VSCROLLER::activate()
{
    int i;

    if(SDL_PointInRect(&mouse,&arrowDn))
     {
         butt.y+=vp->vscrollspeed;
         if((butt.y+butt.h)<dnbound)
            butt.y-=vp->vscrollspeed;
         return;
     }

    if(SDL_PointInRect(&mouse,&arrowUp))
     {
         butt.y-=vp->hscrollspeed;
         if((butt.y)>upbound)
            butt.y+=vp->hscrollspeed;
         return;
     }

    butt.y+=dy;
    if((butt.y<upbound)||(butt.y+butt.h)>dnbound)
        butt.y-=dy;
    else
        {
          for(i=0;i<vp->buttamount;i++)
            {
                vp->pads[i].butt.y=dy*(vp->vscrollspeed);
            }
        }
}

void B_VSCROLLER::draw(SDL_Renderer* nren)
        {
            SDL_SetRenderDrawColorExt(nren,backcolor);
            SDL_RenderDrawRect(nren,&background);
            SDL_SetRenderDrawColorExt(nren,currst);
            SDL_RenderDrawRect(nren,&butt);
            SDL_SetRenderDrawColorExt(nren,arrowcolor[0]);
            SDL_RenderDrawRect(nren,&arrowUp);
            SDL_SetRenderDrawColorExt(nren,arrowcolor[1]);
            SDL_RenderDrawRect(nren,&arrowDn);
        }

void B_VSCROLLER::target(SDL_Renderer* nren)
    {
        SDL_Color tempSt;

        if(SDL_PointInRect(&mouse,&butt))
        {
            tempSt=currst;
            tempSt.a=200;
            SDL_SetRenderDrawColorExt(nren,tempSt);
            SDL_RenderDrawRect(nren,&butt);
        }


        if(SDL_PointInRect(&mouse,&arrowDn))
        {
            tempSt=arrowcolor[0];
            tempSt.a=200;
            SDL_SetRenderDrawColorExt(nren,tempSt);
            SDL_RenderDrawRect(nren,&arrowDn);
        }


        if(SDL_PointInRect(&mouse,&arrowUp))
        {
            tempSt=arrowcolor[1];
            tempSt.a=200;
            SDL_SetRenderDrawColorExt(nren,tempSt);
            SDL_RenderDrawRect(nren,&arrowUp);
        }
    }



void B_SLIDER::activate()
    {
        butt.x+=dx;
        if((butt.x<leftbound)||(butt.x+butt.w)>rightbound)
            butt.x-=dx;
        else
        if(callBack!=nullptr)
            if(callBack(value, object))
                error=true;
    }

void B_SLIDER::draw(SDL_Renderer* nren)
    {
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColorExt(nren,backcolor);
        SDL_RenderDrawRect(nren,&background);
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColorExt(nren,currst);
        SDL_RenderDrawRect(nren,&butt);
    }

void B_SLIDER::target(SDL_Renderer* nren)
    {
        SDL_Color tempSt;

        tempSt=currst;
        tempSt.a=200;
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColorExt(nren,tempSt);
        SDL_RenderDrawRect(nren,&butt);
    }
```

ViewPort.h:

```
    #ifndef VIEWPORT_H_INCLUDED
#define VIEWPORT_H_INCLUDED

#include "buttonClasses.h"
//struct viewPort;

struct viewPort
{
    SDL_Rect viewPort;

    int borderW;
    SDL_Color bordercolor;

    SDL_Color wallpaper;

    int buttamount;
    button* pads=nullptr;
    button* scrollerh=nullptr;
    button* scrollerv=nullptr;
    int hscrollspeed, vscrollspeed;

   // viewPort();

    int subVamount=0;
//    viewPort* subV=nullptr;

    void draw();
    void activate(bool clicked);
    void scrollupd();

    ~viewPort();

};

#endif // VIEWPORT_H_INCLUDED
```

Comment: Функции 1. не должны принимать другой класс иначе как через указатель или ссылку; 2. предварительное объявление, + 3. Определение тел функций вне класса, после объявлений.

Comment: Код покажите...

Comment: Harry, проблема в том, что тело класса и так определено в отдельном срр. У меня есть класс menu, он требует класс viewport,хорошо, класс viewport требует класс кнопок,хорошо,а кнопки требуют и viewport и menu.( и не просто как указатели, они используют именно методы этих классов)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Если вы мне (что вряд ли...), то показал :)

Comment: Присоединяюсь к @HolyBlackCat - код покажите... :) Понимаете, нельзя "исправьте мне проблему, только, во-первых, я вам ее не покажу, а во-вторых, ничего при этом в моем коде не меняйте!" Так не бывает.

Comment: @Harry Ну кода будет много тогда, строчек 200, так можно выкладывать? Я только сегодня зарегался просто.

Comment: Нужен [минимальный пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Если, конечно, мой ответ остался не понят.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функции

1. не должны принимать другой класс иначе как через указатель или ссылку;
2. предварительное объявление, +
3. Определение тел функций вне класса, после объявлений.

Все. Например (с переполнением стека, но лень было писать много :))

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

struct A;

struct B
{
    void out(const A& a) const;
};

struct A
{
    void out(const B& b) const;
};


void B::out(const A& a) const
{
    cout << "b";
    a.out(*this);
};

void A::out(const B& b) const
{
    cout << "a";
    b.out(*this);
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    A a; B b;
    a.out(b);
}
```